# Using dictionary of column names to decide how to multiply through an equation in python

Tags: python, pandas, function

I'm trying to define a function that loops through a dictionary in which keys are a dataframes column names, and the values are discounts associated with that column if the observation qualifies for the discount.  I want to multiply the discounts together and use the product as an offset in a GLM.  I am currently getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-242-0029e2a0de4f> in <module>
----> 1 offset_params(df)

<ipython-input-241-b5343cde7a7e> in offset_params(df)
      8 
      9     for keys, vals in discounts.items():
---> 10         if df[keys] == 0:
     11             offset = offset * 1
     12         else:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1574         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1575                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
-> 1576                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1577 
   1578     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Here is some sample code that is producing the same error:

```
import pandas as pd

discounts = {'discount1_0':[0,1], 'discount1_1':[1,0], 'discount2_0':[0,1],'discount2_1':[1,0]
                         , 'discount3_0':[0,1],'discount3_1':[1,0],'discount1_0':[1,0], 'discount1_1':[0,1]
                         , 'discount2_0':[1,0],'discount2_1':[0,1], 'discount3_0':[1,0],'discount3_1':[0,1]        
            }
df = pd.DataFrame(discounts)

def offset_params(df):
    discounts = {'discount1_0':1, 'discount1_1':.98, 'discount2_0':1,'discount2_1':.95
                         , 'discount3_0':1,'discount3_1':.95,'discount1_0':1, 'discount1_1':.98
                         , 'discount2_0':1,'discount2_1':.95, 'discount3_0':1,'discount3_1':.95
            }

    offset = 1

    for keys, vals in discounts.items():
        if df[keys] == 0:
            offset = offset * 1
        else:
            offset = offset * vals

    return offset
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What are you hoping `df[keys] == 0` will do? `df[keys]` is a column in your dataframe so will be many values in a `pandas.Series` object..

Comment: If the value of the discount is 0, I don't want the offset to multiply by 0 because the lowest value an observation can have is 1 (denoting no discounts).

Comment: You need to show us your dataframe.

Comment: crap!  forgot to copy and paste that in there.  updated for needed info.

Comment: OK. I can answer this now

Answer (score 0):

You need to operate on your dataframe row by row. A function in pandas to do this is `apply`. Rather than passing the whole dataframe to `offset_params` pass it row by row using `apply` to iterate over the whole dataframe.

```
df['offset'] = df.apply(lambda row: offset_params(row), axis=1)

# Then look at your dataframe:

df.head()
```

I would change the variable name `df` in your function to `row` so the code makes more sense.